# Why BigInteger ToByteArray method sometime generate an extra byte?

Tags: c#, system.numerics

Console app :

```
BigInteger tst = 128;

byte[] buffer = tst.ToByteArray();

foreach (byte b in buffer)
    Console.WriteLine(b);

Console.Read();
```

Result :

```
128
0
```

Why BigInteger ToByteArray method sometime generate this extra byte ? I tried that on version 4.7.2 & 4.5.2 of the .Net Framework, same result. Any clue is welcome, you may need System.Numerics reference to compile this code. thx

Comment: Try the same thing with -128. It might be 128, 1 in those byte array. If it is, then the byte is like a sign-byte.

Comment: The answer is its not, you are just thinking about it wrong, there are no extra bytes, there are exactly the right amount of bytes to store what it needs in negative and positive

Comment: Easy enough to find in the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,324)

Comment: Yes, it's because of the sign, thanks